# Is it bad practice to catch the "happy path" in an exception?

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling, try-catch

I have an SQL statement that checks to see if a value is in my database or not. I want to respond with the "happy path" if the value is *not* in the database.
I have found using DbDataReader (.NET) that if a SELECT query can't find the value it throws an exception - so my "happy path" ends up in the exception, not in the main try block.

I can always say "NOT IN" but I don't want to return all of the rows in the database that don't have the value - as this would return many thousands of results where as all I want is just a "no it is not here" type response.

```
public void wristbandScan(string barcode)
    {
        string query = "SELECT ticket FROM tickets WHERE 
                             linked_barcode='" + barcode + "'";

        ValidTicketEventArgs args = new ValidTicketEventArgs();

        try
        {
            var queryResult = _dbRunner.queryThis(query);

            args.Result = false;
            args.Message = "WB already linked";
            args.Barcode = barcode; 
            OnValidTicketEvent(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.updateWristband(barcode);
            this.updateValid();
            args.Result = true;
            args.Message = "WB linked";
            args.Barcode = barcode;
            OnValidTicketEvent(args);
        }
    }
```

It feels wrong to me to catch the happy path in an error statement, but I do not want the lag associated with reading in all the rows with the NOT IN statement.

Is there a better way to do this or is this approach acceptable best practice?

Comment: Yes, very bad practice. Exception are very __expensive__ and should be just that: __Exceptions__, not something you expect to happen, let alone the 'happy' outcome!

Comment: This is what I thought. So how do I get the SELECT statement to not return an exception when it can't find the value? Perhaps the limitation is my knowledge of SQL?

Comment: _Typically, if a SELECT query can't find the value it throws an exception_ Huh? In what situation is that true?? Typically a query returns an empty result set. What are `_dbRunner.queryThis` ??

Comment: It's probably best to start with an ORM (Object to Relational Manager) like Entity Framework (other options are available), at which point you can treat the tables like collections of objects and not have to worry about the underlying SQL code. It would also do away with the potential for an SQL injection attack that your current code is open to.

Comment: I don't know why the `SELECT` would throw an exception if no results are found, it should return an empty set. However, if you only care about the existence of the barcode you could change your query to `COUNT(1) FROM tickets WHERE linked_barcode=<value>`. This would return 0 if no match is found otherwise a value greater than 0 would be returned

Comment: I've reworded it. The `_dbRunner.queryThis` encapsulates `DbDataReader` and some other information that is needed in this part of the code. I've also abstracted it from the implementation because there's a possibility of using either a remote DB or a local DB, and this part of the code doesn't need to know which. When the query returns the DbDataReader object, if it is an empty response the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't have to *fetch* all the records to the client; let's *extract a method* for this. Assuming that you work with `MS Sql`:

```
 public bool hasScanCode(string barcode) {
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(barcode)) 
     return false;

   //DONE: paramterize queries 
   string query = 
      @"SELECT ticket 
          FROM tickets 
         WHERE linked_barcode = @prm_BarCode";

   using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string_here)) {
     conn.Open();

     using (var q = new SqlCommand(conn, query)) {
       //TODO: q.Parameters.Add is a better choice
       q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_BarCode", barcode.Trim()); 

       using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
         // we read (fetch) at most 1 record
         // if empty cursor - no record with given barcode 
         return reader.Read(); 
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

then we can use it:

```
 public void wristbandScan(string barcode) {
   bool result = hasScanCode(barcode); 

   ValidTicketEventArgs args = new ValidTicketEventArgs() { 
     Result = result,
     Message = result ? "WB linked" : "WB already linked",
     Barcode = barcode, 
   };  

   OnValidTicketEvent(args);       
 }
```

Please, remember - *exceptions* are for *exceptional situations*. Exceptions are very *slow* (stack unrolling wants resources); they are not *readable* - `catch`, in fact, works as a notorious `goto`; they are *dangerous* - in your current code you `catch` *too many exceptions*: e.g. `AccessViolationException` if it's thrown somewhere within `dbRunner.queryThis` will be efficiently *masked*.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I reworked my implementation and this worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Create and call a StoredProcedure which can to handle the empty situation and return no rows instead of an exception.

Then handle the no rows scenario outside the `try/catch`.